# Experimental evidence of interaction out of thermal euilibrium?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, standard-model, antimatter, baryogenesis

Sakharov gave three conditions for the matter-antimatter asymmetry observed in the universe.

(1) Baryon number violation: Don’t have any experimental confirmation yet.
(2) C-symmetry and CP-symmetry violation: Observed experimentally
(3) Interaction out of thermal equilibrium: My question is here; is there any kind of the previous study done or any study going for this search?

I will be thankful if someone gives any kind of link to some paper or explains about this search.

Comment: did you try search engines? here is a talk interaction out of thermal euilibrium? https://indico.cern.ch/event/686555/contributions/2956954/attachments/1681128/2700889/Non-thermal_WIMP_ICHEP.pdf  , from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.00820.pdf   ,  also https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/952/1/012006/pdf  . I searched for "baryon asymmetry interaction out of thermal euilibrium"

Comment: Thank you for comment. I searched but didn't find any satisfactory answers. So if I understood, there is no interaction out of thermal equilibrium observed experimentally?

Comment: I believe so, other than the baryon asymmetry it is invoked to explain. So if there is a mathematical connection in one of the papers, the baryon asymmetry would be the experimental observation. In heavy ion collisions they are trying , but they use the cosmic data as example for qcd! https://indico.cern.ch/event/598530/contributions/2547224/attachments/1517124/2368095/HeavyIonLecture_Lecture1.pdf

Comment: They consider the various cosmological particle  decouplings as examples out of thermal equilibrium

Comment: But the decouplings magnitude or number may be so small from which we can't say that there is some interaction out of thermal equilibrium.

Comment: I think they mean that they are not in thermal equilibrium, the  photons after decoupling for example, with the rest if the cosmos so they retain the picture of when they decoupled.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! I get some hint now I will study more about this